# Jcrop not cropping the selected area on Large Images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop in my web development project. Everything is working fine but in large images not cropping the exact area that i'm selecting. Please someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: this link can be helpful http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html

Comment: I follow this but not working. have you more suggestions to solve this problem?